# How I can get first value of database for each id_ope?

Tags: asp-classic

My data missing for first row when id_ope change
when I query data from the database it shows like this below

[image]

And after coding
[image]
this is my code in ASP-classic

```
test = 0
for x = 0 to emailRow
id_ope = arrx(0,x)
id_boat = arrx(1,x)
bname = arrx(2,x)
' email = arrx(3,x)
body = "<table>"&arrcon&"<table>"
if id_ope&"" <> "2" then
    if test = 0 then
        test = id_ope
            content = "<tr><td>"&bname&id_ope&"</td><td>"&id_boat&"</td></tr>" 
        arrcon = arrcon +content
    elseif test = id_ope then
        content = "<tr><td>"&bname&id_ope&"</td><td>"&id_boat&"</td></tr>" 
        arrcon = arrcon +content
    else 
        content = "<tr><td>"&bname&id_ope&"</td><td>"&id_boat&"</td></tr>" 
        arrcon = arrcon +content

        mailBody = body
        arrcon = ""

        test = id_ope
        response.write mailBody 
    end if
end if
next
```

And this is my SQL query

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 30 boat.id_ope, 
                   boat.id_boat, 
                   boat.Name2
FROM Boat
     INNER JOIN Commission ON Commission.id_boat = Boat.id_boat
WHERE Commission.Commission = '0'
ORDER BY boat.id_ope DESC;
```

Comment: it's a bit hard to help you when you talk about a SQL query but you show us an array we know nothing about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See in comment code

```
content = "<tr><td>"&bname&id_ope&"</td><td>"&id_boat&"</td></tr>" 
            arrcon = arrcon +content // add value

            mailBody = body
            arrcon = "" //set = null

            test = id_ope
            response.write mailBody
```

I think your set arrcon = "" after add value